# ILP Problem to minimize two functions one after the other

Tags: linear-programming

I am working with a ILP problem. In the problem I would like to minimize `f(x0+..+xn)` and then if multiple **optimal** solutions exist, minimize `g(x0+..+xn)` from the subset of those optimal solutions.

I am using SYMPHONY to minimize the first function. If i turn it into a bi-criteria problem, i get efficient results which i am not interested in. Is there any technique/solver out there which would allow me to do this ? Or if i can get multiple solutions i would be okay in checking each at a time to minimize `g(x0+..+xn)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

May be a lexicographic approach:

1. Solve with obj `f(x0+..+xn)`. Let `f0` be the optimal objective value.
2. Add a constraint `f(x0+..+xn)=f0` to the model. (May be add a little bit of wiggle room).
3. Solve with obj `g(x0+..+xn)`.

Comment: Yep, I do exactly this myself. But you might want to do `f(x0+...+xn)<=f0` to preserve convexity. If `f` is linear it won't matter, but if it involves some sort of piecewise convex objective it will be best to use the inequality.